# How to Check Status, Start and execute some commands inside azure virtual machine from azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-managed-identity

I am using a logic app which gets triggered when a new blob is uploaded in a storage container and the next step is to run a azure function with uploaded file as input. The purpose of azure function is to check whether a particular Virtual Machine is running or not, if not start the VM and send the file inside the VM for some processing. My function is getting executed but it's not showing status of VM and not doing what I mentioned in the code and even I'm not getting any errors. How to solve this?
Code:
HTTP Trigger Function:

```
import logging
import os
import azure.functions as func
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
import paramiko
def check_vm_status(resource_group_name, vm_name, subscription_id):
  logging.info("inside check_vm_status function")
# Create a ComputeManagementClient using DefaultAzureCredential
  compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(
      credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
      subscription_id=subscription_id
  )

  logging.info("Getting vm Status")
# Get VM status
  vm = compute_client.virtual_machines.get(
      resource_group_name=resource_group_name,
      vm_name=vm_name,
  )
  logging.info(f'power_state = {vm.power_state}') # type: ignore
  return vm.power_state # type: ignore

def start_virtual_machine(resource_group_name, vm_name, subscription_id):
  logging.info('inside start_virtual_machine function')
# Create a ComputeManagementClient using DefaultAzureCredential
  compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(
      credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
      subscription_id=subscription_id
  )

  logging.info("Starting the VM")
# Start the virtual machine
  compute_client.virtual_machines.start( # type: ignore
      resource_group_name=resource_group_name,
      vm_name=vm_name
  )

def send_files_to_virtual_machine(hostname, username, password, local_path, remote_path):
  logging.info('Inside send_files_to_vm function')
# Create an SSH client using paramiko
  ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
  ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

  try:
      logging.info("Connecting SSH")
    # Connect to the virtual machine
      ssh.connect(hostname, username=username, password=password)

    # Use SFTP to upload files to the virtual machine
      with ssh.open_sftp() as sftp:
          sftp.put(local_path, remote_path)

  finally:
      ssh.close()

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
 try:
  logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
  subscription_id = "5cab9de4-9b79-495f-9052-f52c43de62ee"
  resource_group_name = "SOLUTIONSTEAM"
  virtual_machine_name = "Dragen-VM"
  vm_username = "<my_user_email>"
  vm_password = "<my_user_password>"
  vm_hostname = "172.174.254.198"

  req_body = req.get_json()
  print("Http Trigger Function Request Body:", req_body)
  local_file_path = req_body['Files']
  remote_file_path = "/home/sai"

  vm_status = check_vm_status(resource_group_name, virtual_machine_name, subscription_id)
  logging.info(f'vm_status = {vm_status}')

  if vm_status == "VM running":
        print(f'VM {virtual_machine_name} is running')
        # return func.HttpResponse("VM is running", status_code=200)
  elif vm_status == "VM deallocated":
        start_virtual_machine(resource_group_name, virtual_machine_name, subscription_id)
        # return func.HttpResponse("VM is deallocated", status_code=200)
  else:
        return func.HttpResponse("VM status unknown", status_code=200)

  send_files_to_virtual_machine(vm_hostname, vm_username, vm_password, local_file_path, remote_file_path)

  return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {req_body}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
 except Exception as e:
     return func.HttpResponse(f"Error: {str(e)}", status_code=500)
```